# I can't retrieve the value typed in a text input using Javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, onclick

I have a problem, when i try to retrieve the value I have typed in the text input, and I try to print it in alert , it shows nothing, the variable is empty
here is the code:

 I have here the input textfield 'Montant', i would like to retrieve it using the onClick event on the button on the bottom

```
<form  name="formEspece" method="get" action="{{route('EffectuerPaiement')}}" >
<div class="modal-body">
    <p>Veuillez saisir le montant à payer pour cette échéance</p>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Montant:</label>
            <input required type="number" id="idMontant1"class="form-control" placeholder="Saisissez un montant" name="Montant" >
        </div>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick='return test(document.getElementById("idMontant1").value,{{$paiement->montant-$totalPaiement}})' value="valider"/>
</div></form>
```

here is the script:

```
<script>function test(a,b){
window.alert('a= '+a+'b= '+b);}</script>
```

it shows nothing, notice that i am using Bootstrap, and LARAVEL

here is a more detailed code I retreive it from my own project:

```
@foreach($inscriptions as $inscription)
<?php
// some treatments
?>
<tr  class="{{$rowstyle}}">
    <td><img src="images/{{ $inscription->photo }}"></td>
    <td>{{ $inscription->cne }}</td>
    <td>{{ $inscription->nom }}</td>
    <td>{{ $inscription->prenom }}</td>
    <td>{{ $inscription->ville }}</td>
    <!-- the  button  who open the forms modal-->
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="{{"#smallModalEspece".$count}}">Espèce</button>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="{{ route('retirer',[ 'cne' => $inscription->cne ]) }}"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
        <a href="{{ route('detailetudiant',[ 'id' => $inscription->id ]) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
            <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Détails
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>

<!-- the modal who contains the form -->

<div id="{{"smallModalEspece".$count}}" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Paiement en espèce</h4>
                </div>
                <form  name="formEspece" method="get" action="{{route('EffectuerPaiement')}}" >
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <h3>Le montant restant à payer pour l'étudiant {{\fc\etudiant::find($inscription->cne)->nom.' '.\fc\etudiant::find($inscription->cne)->prenom}} est : {{$paiement->montant-$totalPaiement}}</h3>
                        <p>Veuillez saisir le montant à payer pour cette écheance</p>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="hidden" name="MontantPaye" value="{{$paiement->montant-$totalPaiement}}"/>
                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Montant:</label>
                                <input required type="number" id="idMontant1"class="form-control" placeholder="Saisissez un montant" name="Montant" >
                            </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value=" {{ csrf_token() }} ">
                        <input type="hidden" name="idpaiment"  value="{{$paiement->idPaiement}}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="nbrEcheance"  value="{{$nbrE}}">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <input type="button" id="#buttonid" class="btn btn-primary" onclick='test(document.getElementById("idMontant1").value,{{$paiement->montant-$totalPaiement}})' value="valider"/>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Does the alert actually fire?

Comment: Remove `return` from `onclick`.

Comment: what is `{{$paiement->montant-$totalPaiement}}`?

Comment: i removed return , and it's still not working, in my code , i have some hidden inputs, i have any problem with them

Comment: checked your JS console for errors?

Comment: spascarello , yes it actually fire

Comment: Marc B , i've check it , and there is no problem

Comment: As Marc said, check your console. I tried your code (replaced the curly brackets with static data), and the first problem was you need an space here (between id and class): `id="idMontant1"class="form-control"` (assuming it is the copy/pasted code). Anyhow, it worked for me with static data.

Comment: your script works for me: [**http://jsfiddle.net/ug8xvptv/**](http://jsfiddle.net/ug8xvptv/)

Comment: I have Bootstrap , don't you think it  causes a conflict ?

Comment: Maybe. Post a demo of the issue

Comment: need 10 reputation to post pictures

Comment: a picture isn't a demo. Use a [**Stack snippet**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or create a demo on jsfiddle.  BTW: works also with bootstrap:

Comment: Thank you for your patience Dr.Molle http://jsfiddle.net/tkoLtj5w/2/

Comment: @Ismail Addou: Your fiddle also works(there was only a wrong setting in the fiddle. You've chosen the onload-option, because of that the function was undefined, but that isn't related to your question). Fixed fiddle: [**http://jsfiddle.net/tkoLtj5w/3/**](http://jsfiddle.net/tkoLtj5w/3/)

Comment: i will give you more explanation, the form is in a Bootstrap MODAL , I have a set of rows , and for each row we have a button, who open the modal wich contains the formular, the first row works, but others don't work especially for the text input, but all the hidden inputs are OK

Comment: @Ismail Addou: [see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30714864/459897)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID's must be unique, but you use the same ID `idMontant1` for each number-input.
(A browser may not guess which element you mean, he will always select the same input)

Possible solution:
you may omit the ID, instead pass the button as argument to `test()` .
Via the button you'll be able to find the desired input:

- find the form(it's the `form`-property of the button)
- find the input with the `name` `Montant` within the form(e.g. via `element.querySelector`)

Simple demo(I've removed the irrelevant markup)

```js
function test(btn) {
  var val = btn.form.querySelector('input[name="Montant"]').value;
  alert(val);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" name="Montant" value="12" />
  <input type="button" onclick="return test(this)" value="valider" />
</form>
<form>
  <input type="number" name="Montant" value="34" />
  <input type="button" onclick="return test(this)" value="valider" />
</form>
<form>
  <input type="number" name="Montant" value="56" />
  <input type="button" onclick="return test(this)" value="valider" />
</form>
<form>
  <input type="number" name="Montant" value="78" />
  <input type="button" onclick="return test(this)" value="valider" />
</form>
```

Comment: I used a variable $count to make difference between inputs, <input type="text" id="idModal.{{$count}} ... />

Answer (score 0):

add an id to the button and try this

```
<script>
    $("#buttonid").click(function(){
    var in = $("#idMontant1").val();
    window.alert(in);});
</script>
```

Comment: still the same problem, i think is a conflict with Bootstrap, don't you think so ?

Comment: check the javascript references. or try it `alert(in)` without `window.`

Comment: still the same problem, my code and your's works perfectly in other projects, but not in mine :/

Comment: can you post the javascript references? also check their inheritance. if you are using a master page you should extend it and also call the section where you want the form to show.

Comment: actually I am begginer in javascript, i need more explanation for what you need me to do

Comment: do you have something like this `<script src="{{asset('Scripts/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>` in your project?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below script:

```
<script>
    function affich(montant){
        windows.alert('montant');
    }
</script>
```

Then in input you can do:

```
onclick="affich('montant')"
```

Comment: can you explain the difference to the function in the question(I don't see any except a different function-name and the fact that you didn't use the supplied argument)